# on running flutter project tflite is giving error

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, flutter-dependencies, tensorflow-lite, tflite

How to solve it. Help
I am facing these issues.
[image: error I got]

[image]

Comment: are you using any api ?

Comment: in this proj yes...... but in other apps also giving same issues and error

Comment: Can you try cleaning the cache file, try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: i did many times....nothing happened